# null ContentItem in Orchard

Tags: orchardcms

First - disclaimer: I know I should not do it like this, but use LazyField instead and that model should not contain logic and I will modify my code accordingly, but I wanted to explore the 1-n relationship between content items and orchard in general.

I'm creating a system where user can respond to selected job offer, so I have two content types - Job, which lists all available jobs, and JobAnswer which contains my custom part and provides link to appropriate Job content item:

```
public class JobPart : ContentPart<JobPartRecord>
{        

    public ContentItem Job
    {            

        get
        {
               if (Record.ContentItemRecord != null)
                {
                    var contentItem = ContentItem.ContentManager.Get(Record.Job.Id);
                    return contentItem;
                }

            var nullItem = ContentItem.ContentManager.Query("Job").List().First();
            return nullItem;

            }
         set { Record.Job = value.Record; }
    }
}
```

This works, but I'm not sure how should I handle returning a null contentItem, when creating new content item, now it just returns first Job content item, which is far from ideal.

Comment: why would you want it to return a value when it is null? shouldn't it then just be null? Is this part attached to the Job or the JobAnswer? If to the JobAnswer, you should consider a rename

Comment: The part is attached to JobAnswer, but it could be added to any content type referencing the Job content type, hence the name. Also, at first I had here code which returned null when there was no content item attached, but that caused null reference exception in the edit method of the part driver and the apropriate view in edit form was not rendered.

Comment: Job and JobAnswer look like they should be modeled using the List feature. There are almost no cases that require building your own relationship from scratch.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy: Thanks, that is an excellent idea! I have even read your [article](http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/many-ways-to-relate-orchard-things-part-3-lists) about this, but I forgot about it.